# difference between well known books in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

Hi All: I don't know much about the deep-learning field but I was looking around in case I ever wanted to try to look into it more deeply (no pun intended).

My question is, with regard to neural networks/deep learning/reinforcement learning, there seem to be three major texts, aleast based on my looking around :

1. the text by Goodfellow, Bengio and Courville titled "Deep Learning".
2. the text by Richard Sutton titled "Reinforcement Learning."
3. the text by Michael Nielsen titled "Neural Networks and Deep Learning".

My question is two-fold:

A) Do these books cover the same topics ? I don't know the difference between re-inforcement learning and deep learning which is the reason for the question.

B) Which text would be recommended for someone who is familiar with neural networks only at the level of the introductory course given by Andrew Ng at Coursera ? Basically, I understand the basic neural network and the backpropagation algorithm.

Thank you very much for answers to above and in general any wisdom-advice related to starting to learn about the field. My background is Ph.D in statistics and OR so I am pretty familiar with the optimization algorithms such as gradient descent, BFGS etc.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better question for https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but I highly recommend Francois Chollet's book Deep Learning with Python. It's very readable and quickly gives great practical knowledge.

Comment: Reinforcement learning is concerned with approximate solutions to stochastic dynamic programming / stochastic control problems. In modern applications the function approximation schemes use neural network architecture. Otherwise, it's not related to deep learning.

Comment: Thanks to all. Q the Platypus: I didn't know that there was an ai.stackexchange.com.  little0: your comment is useful. David: You explained the difference quite nicely.